# how to print list elements as shown in above

Tags: python

i need to access first element of nested lists and print it and also need to access second elements of every list and print it

```
details = {"name":["suresh","ramesh"],"age":[25,26],"city":["hyd","chn"]}

# print(" my name is {}, and age is {} and coming from {}".format())
```

## required output:

```
# my name is suresh, age is 25 and coming from hyd
# my name is ramesh, age is 26 and coming from chn
```

unable to write

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip()` method with `dict.values()`:

```
details = {"name":["suresh","ramesh"],"age":[25,26],"city":["hyd","chn"]}

s = "my name is {}, and age is {} and coming from {}"

for detail in zip(*details.values()):
    print(s.format(*detail))
```

Prints:

```
my name is suresh, and age is 25 and coming from hyd
my name is ramesh, and age is 26 and coming from chn
```

EDIT: It's better to see what each step is doing:

`dict.values()` holds:

```
dict_values([['suresh', 'ramesh'], [25, 26], ['hyd', 'chn']])
```

`[*zip(*details.values())]` holds:

```
[('suresh', 25, 'hyd'), ('ramesh', 26, 'chn')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the Reference from Andrej's answer and here is modified code

```
details = {"name":["suresh","ramesh"],"age":[25,26],"city":["hyd","chn"]}

s = "my name is {}, and age is {} and coming from {}"

print(*map(lambda detail: s.format(*detail) , zip(*details.values())) , sep ='\n' )
```

This returns the expected output

```
my name is suresh, and age is 25 and coming from hyd
my name is ramesh, and age is 26 and coming from chn
```